# Using mechanize to validate a set of url's

Tags: ruby, http, mechanize

I'm trying to validate an array of urls using mechanize. I am getting a 404 for one of the urls that is ending my loop instead of going through the rescue. I want the loop to continue even if it hits a 404. Am I doing something wrong with the begin/rescue syntax? I'm just displaying them in terminal for the time being.

```
a.get(url) do |page|
  begin
    puts url
    puts page.title
  rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, Net::HTTPNotFound
    puts "404!- " + "#{url}"
    next
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your begin/rescue/end around a.get, i.e:

```
begin
  a.get(url) do |page|
    puts url
    puts page.title
  end
rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, Net::HTTPNotFound
  puts "404!- " + "#{url}"
  next
end
```